# Angular 4 | how to format date using pipe?

Tags: angular, pipe

Good day,

how can i format my date using pipe in angular? im having trouble on it since it always return wrong date.

Below is how i format my date.

Actual value
20170901

```
<span>{{apidata.DeliveryDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
```

it returns (1970-01-01)

how can i fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the Angular docs for [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) already? What format are you expecting?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Answer (score 0):

[DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) converts a `Date` object or date saved in ISO string. What you are trying to format is a number (that's a real backend design issue)... You can convert your date into real format, e.g. by using `moment` library:

```
apidata.deliveryDate = moment(apidata.DeliveryDate, 'YYYYMMDD').toISOString();
```

And then it will work. You can also create custom pipe that will convert and format the "date" for you. Example code for in-component solution:

```
// regular imports
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Component({
  template: `<span>{{apidata.deliveryDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>`
})
export class SomeComponent {
  apidata: any;

  constructor(someService: SomeService) { // <-- this is a service you get your data from
    this.someService.getApiData().subscribe((apidata) => {
      this.apidata = apidata;
      this.apidata.deliveryDate = moment(apidata.DeliveryDate, 'YYYYMMDD').toISOString();
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give me example on it? im just new in angular 2. and how can i apply that on my component?

Comment: Here you go... In the future, consider adding example code to the question if you expect one in an answer ;)

Comment: thanks man hehehe next time :) can i also create custom pipe from this? because moment.js is really data consuming for just small conversion like this.

Comment: Sure you can, it will be quite challenging without using any library, good luck!

Comment: @JydonMah all you need to do is convert your date into a `YYYY-MM-DD` string then create a new date using `new Date('2017-09-01')` without using any bloated library

Comment: just like {{myDate.substring(6) | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd''}} ?? my date is in array so should i do is to catch all date in array and convert it all to string?